# PHP Curl return different results from URL in browser

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am using PHP Curl with this code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.segundamano.mx/anuncios/ciudad-de-mexico/alvaro-obregon/florida/renta-inmuebles/departamentos?precio=0-10000');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0");

$uagent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:22.0) Firefox/22.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/36.0.1985.125 Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
```

My question is.. why PHP Curl gives different result Than Searching URL in BROWSER?

PHP Curls gives a big BODY CONTENT... with this LINE...
In Spanish... "No encontramos resultados para tu búsqueda..."
In English.....There are no results for your search...

What happen with this URL?
How Can I CURL and read by code this URL and get the REAL RESULTS AS BROWSER?

Help me please!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because <s>JavaScript is the root of all evil.</s> the website gets the search results you want with AJAX after you've succesfully loaded the page. Just open the "network" tab of your browser inspection tool and see the requests flying around.

Fun part: the website does have a (seemingly authorized) API that it can talk too, maybe you can try that? https://webapi.segundamano.mx/nga/api/v1.1/public

Answer (score 1):

The link you have mentioned is a single-page web application or web site that interacts with the user by dynamically rewriting the current page rather than loading entire new pages from a server.

Also, this website is using vue js.

Please find the below links for more details.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application
https://vuejs.org/

Comment: Thanks buddy that was really helpful.